# I have a about input bottun

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .dark {
            background-color: black;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="document.body.className='dark'" value="dark" />
    <input type="button" onclick="document.body.className=''" value="reset" />
</body>

</html>
```

I have two buttons and two effects.

The button is reduced to one

If the background is black, the button name is reset,
How do I make the button name dark when the background is white?

Comment: What have you tried so far? maybe something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/hk335jLk/

Comment: '')thanks this is it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function clickme ()
        {

            if(document.body.style.background =='black')
            {   
                document.body.style.background='white';
                document.getElementById("button").value="dark";
            }
            else
            {
                document.body.style.background='black';
                document.getElementById("button").value="reset";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body >
    <input type="button"  id="button" onclick="clickme()" value="dark" />
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what you are looking for:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.dark')[0].style.backgroundColor == 'white' ? document.querySelectorAll('.dark')[0].style.color = black;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest downloading and using jQuery so your code is cross browser compliant and it's easier to perform whatever you want to do. That said, below is your code updated to work.

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.querySelector('body.dark') ? document.body.className='' : document.body.className='dark';" value="toggledark" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres what i think you mean, i set up a button that on click changes the body to the background colour of the text showing on the button once clicked.

Its created in jQuery.

Here's a link to a [live demo](http://codepen.io/fun/pen/yMMxJP?editors=1011)

Heres the html

```
<button class = 'button' > dark </div>
```

Heres the jQuery

```
$('.button').click(function() {

  if ($(this).text() == 'dark') {
    $(this).text('white');
    $('body').addClass('dark');
    $('body').removeClass('white');
  } else {
    $(this).text('dark');
    $('body').addClass('white');
    $('body').removeClass('dark');
  }

});
```